# SBT Compile for uber jar

Tags: scala, compilation, sbt, offline

What is the best way to make a SBT project work in offline environment?
There is any ways to compile it outside (in network env),
e.g uber jar with all its dependencies, and then in the offline env
just run it?

For example in Java Maven,
We can compile it with uber jar with all dependencies,
and then in the offline env just `java -jar MyJar.jar` ...

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand correctly your question, sbt uses Apache Ivy to implement dependency management and save them into .ivy2 directory in first compile and then You can use it in offline env.

Comment: What is the problem with the offline mode in sbt?

Answer (score 1):

Best bet for creating an uber/fat jar is the [sbt assembly plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly).  Include it in your project by putting something like the following in `project/assembly.sbt`

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.6")
```

Then just running `sbt assembly` should create a jar with all the dependencies in `target/scala_$SCALA_VERSION`.  You may need to designate a main class for the jar if you want to run it with `java -jar` (as opposed to `java -cp $jarfile $mainclass`):

```
mainClass in assembly := Some("package.mainClass")
```